# How number of MFCC coefficients depends on the length of the file

Tags: voice-recognition, mfcc

I have a voice data with length 1.85 seconds, then I extract its feature using MFCC (with libraby from [James Lyson](https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features)). It returns 184 x 13 features. I am using 10 milisecond frame step, 25 miliseconds frame size, and 13 coefficients from DCT. How can it return 184? I still can not understand because the last frame's length is not 25 miliseconds. Is there any formula which explain how can it return 184? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a picture that can explain you things, basically the last window takes more space than previous ones.

If you have 184 windows, the region you cover is 183 * 10 + 25 or approximately 1855 ms.

[image]